# Improving camshift algorithm in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using camshift algorithm of opencv for object tracking. The input is being taken from a webcam and the object is tracked between successive frames. How can I make the tracking stronger? If I move the object at a rapid rate, tracking fails. Also when the object is not in the frame there are false detections. How do I improve this ?

Comment: I don't think the camshift algorithm alone will solve this problem.

Comment: Choosing an algorithm for tracking depends strongly on what kind of object are you tracking. Also are you tracking or just localizing the object ?

Answer (score 2):

Object tracking is an active research area in computer vision.  There are numerous algorithms to do it, and none of them work 100% of the time.

If you need to track in real time, then you need something simple and fast.  I am assuming that you have a way of segmenting a moving object from the background.  Then you can compute a representation of the object, such as a color histogram, and compare it to the the object you find in the next frame.  You should also check that the object has not moved too far between frames.  If you want to try more advanced motion tracking, then you should look up Kalman Filter.

Determining that an object is not in the frame is also a big problem.  First, what kinds of objects are you trying to track?  People? Cars? Dogs?  You can build an object classifier, which would tell you whether or not the moving object in the frame is your object of interest, as opposed to noise or some other kind of object.  A classifier can be something very simple, such as a constraint on size, or it can be very complicated.  In the latter case you need to learn about features that can be computed, classification algorithms, such as support vector machines, and you would need to collect training images to train it.

In short, a reliable tracker is not an easy thing to build.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you find the object in the first two frames.  From that information, you can extrapolate where you'd expect the object in the third frame.  Instead of using a generic find-the-object algorithm, you can use a slower, more sophisticated (and thus hopefully more reliable) algorithm by limiting it to check in the vicinity that the extrapolation predicts.  It may not be exactly where you expect (perhaps the velocity vector is changing), but you should certainly be able to reduce the area that's checked.

This should help reduce the number of times some other part of the frame is misidentified as the object (because you're looking at a smaller portion of the frame and because you're using a better feature detector).

Update the extrapolations based on what you find and iterate for the next frame.

If the object goes out of frame, you fall back to your generic feature detector, as you do with the first two frames, and try again to get a "lock" when the object returns to the view.

Also, if you can, throw as much light into the physical scene as possible.  If the scene is dim, the webcam will use a longer exposure time, leading to more motion blur on moving objects.  Motion blur can make it very hard for the feature detectors (though it can give you information about direction and speed).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you expand the border of the search window in camShift it makes the algorithm a bit more adaptive to fast moving objects, although it can introduced some irregularities. try just making the border of your window 10% bigger and see what happens.